# Passing a component into React setState value

Tags: reactjs, meteor, session-variables

I've got a Meteor app using React. I've added Session variables and want to pass the new Session value (which will be another React component) into another react component.

The user will click the p-tag in the SideNav and reset the Session to a React component.

**SideNav component**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Session } from 'meteor/session';
import SonataContent from './sonata-content';

export default () => {
  injectSonataText = () => {
    const sonataContent = <SonataContent/>;
    Session.set('MainContent', sonataContent); /* Set Session value to component */
  };

  return (
    <div className="side-nav">
      <h2>Explore</h2>
      <p onClick={this.injectSonataText.bind(this)}><i className="material-icons">child_care</i><span>&nbsp;Sonatas</span></p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

In the MainWindow, Tracker.autorun re-runs and sets the state to the component and renders the new state value.

**Main Window component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Session } from 'meteor/session';
import { Tracker } from 'meteor/tracker';


export default class MainWindow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: ""
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.mainWindowTracker = Tracker.autorun(() => {
      const text = Session.get('MainContent');
      this.setState({text: text});
  });
}

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.mainWindowTracker.stop();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <p>{this.state.text}</p>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm getting an error "Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child". Is this caused by the  component being used in setState? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: take this.state.text out of return and console.log it iright after the render outside of return. What is it

Comment: It's actually printing as undefined. Hmm.

Comment: If I console.log the component itself, I get an object. If I console.log the Session value, I get {key: null, ref: null, props: {}, _owner: null, _store: {}}. If I console.log this.state.text in ManiWindow, I get undefined.

Comment: The answer is to stop using Session - as it means you are trying to do something the wrong way!  You need to implement a wrapper component around your 2 main/side components that can orchestrate the 'state' itself through the proper ("setState") methods, using the standard approach of cascading props for values and state-setting function callbacks.

Comment: @Andy You're absolutely correct. Sessions have their use, but this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

[Session set function](https://docs.meteor.com/api/session.html#Session-set) accepts as a value [EJSON-able Object](https://docs.meteor.com/api/ejson.html) which I think may not work with React Object.

However I would try (only a guess though):

```
injectSonataText = () => {
  Session.set('MainContent', SonataContent); /* Set Session value to component */
};
```

...

```
export default class MainWindow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Component: null,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.mainWindowTracker = Tracker.autorun(() => {
      const MainContent = Session.get('MainContent');
      this.setState({Component: MainContent});
  });
}

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.mainWindowTracker.stop();
  }

  render() {
    const { Component } = this.state;
    return (
      <p>
        {
          Component && <Component />
        }
      </p>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't get that to work. console.logging SonataContent reveals "function () {
  return React.createElement("div", null, "Injected Sonata component");
}"